# Two way databinding within Autocomplete matInput

Tags: angular, autocomplete, form-control, two-way-binding

I'm using a material autocomplete input to search an article from a database, i was working with a normal input in a table column with ngModel directive for two-way databinding and wanted to change this input to an autocomplete input so i added as Angular mentionned in documentation a formControl in the input so i can subscribe to valueChanges in the Component

> Template

```
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let ligneFacture of facture.lignesFacture; let i =index;">
  <td>
    <form>
      <mat-form-field >
         <input type="text" class="form-control" matInput [formControl]="articleKeyword"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto [(ngModel)]="ligneFacture.articleId">
         <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let article of articles;" [value]="article.id">
              {{article.libelle}}
           </mat-option>
         </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </td>
```

> TypeScript

```
articleKeyword = new FormControl();

ngOnInit() {
  //some code here 

         this.articleKeyword.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.articleService.queryByKeyword(value).subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse<IArticle[]>) => {
            this.articles = res.body;
        },
        (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    ));
```

The Autocomplete works fine and call my Rest webservice whenever the value of the input changes and the user can choose his article and submit to save in my database then the problem is here : cant bind correctly the view of the input with my choosen articles recieved from database knowing that without the autocomplete input and the need for formControl , ngModel was working fine to do the binding work so my question here : is  there a solution how to subscribe for valuechanges on ngModel ? so i can replace the [formControl] utility here knowing that the use of both ngModel and formControl is deprecated in as mentionned here  https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective#use-with-ngmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the [FormControl] and use insted the (ngModelChange) who fires the change of your input. it would look something like that

```
 <input type="text" matInput (ngModelChange)='searchFunction($event)'
       [matAutocomplete]="auto [(ngModel)]="ligneFacture.articleId">
```

and in your typescript your search function that gets the values from the back end:

```
searchFunction() {//Code here }
```

Here is a stackblitz showing the functionning of the NgModelChange 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzw7by

Comment: i added the function in TS and past it to ngModelChange in the input like you mentionned but this function is never called to fire the change of my input, i tried to debug and the function is called only once when the component is builded

    `searchFunction(event: any) {
        this.articleService.queryByKeyword(event.target.value).subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IArticle[]>) => {
                this.articles = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
    }`

Comment: Are you sure you're using it right, you can recheck my answer, there's a small stackblitz explaining the behaviour of the NgModelChange, maybe it can help

Comment: I was using ngModel directive within a form so i needed to add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" now it works fine thank you